# How is data stored in arrays from getValue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google Sheets looking as part of a script to store data in a range to an array then to check whether a certain column has an "Y" in so I can loop through and store these columns in new arrays.

I have the following code but am getting this error - "TypeError: Cannot read property "0.0" from undefined."

```
var data = sheet.getRange("A6:U37").getValues;

if (data[20][i]=="Y"){
```

(The if code is generating the error)

Believe I am misunderstanding how the range is stored in the array causing the error any advice?

Comment: Can't you just `console.log(data)` and see what you get back...? According to you and the error `data[20]` is `undefined`, so the variable is simply not what you expect it to be, or the array length is less than 21.

Comment: Thanks thats helped - I'd forgotten the () after getValues

Comment: You should try to use debugging before, like showed on the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

In the first line of code you provided, you are referencing the function `getValues` rather than actually calling it. In order to do so, you just have to modify the code as follows:

```js
var data = sheet.getRange("A6:U37").getValues();

if (data[20][i]=="Y"){
```

Next time you have issues similar to this one, you can consider using [logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) or other [debugging techniques](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) in order to debug your script.